# App Saves Selected Video Data iOS

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, uiimagepickercontroller

So I have this App where the user loads a video from the Camera Roll with the `UIImagePickerController`, my code looks like this:

```
var videosPlaylist:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

func loadVideo()
{
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.shouldAutorotate()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.videoQuality = .TypeHigh
    picker.mediaTypes = NSArray(object: kUTTypeMovie) as! [String]
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then in the `imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])` the code looks like this:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) 
{
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]!)")!
    let videoURL = url
    if videosPlaylist.count > 0 //This way I get the user to save just one video to the array.
    {
        videosPlaylist.replaceObjectAtIndex(0, withObject: videoURL)
    }else if videosPlaylist.count == 0
    {
        videosPlaylist.addObject(videoURL)
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now the problem is that each time the user selects a video, the "Documents & Data" in the iPhone Storage, keeps increasing.

[image]

How can I stop the App saving the video data when I'm never using `NSUserDefaults` to save data?